# Approving app by tenant admin does nothing and “Invalid ID for a SharePoint App”

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-addin, csom

I have a provider hosted app that requires permission to read "user profile". When I add the permission in my manifest file and deploy it I get the message "Your tenant administrator has to approve this app". Since I am a TA I request approval and also approve the app on the "/appcatalog/apprequest"(_layouts/15/addanapp.aspx) page. After that the app on my "waiting for approval"-page, it says "Approved" under the app but:

1. When I go to site content page it still says that my app needs approval and I can chose to re-do the approval again and again
2. When I click on "app information" on the addanapp.aspx-page I get the message "Invalid ID for a SharePoint app".

I have registered the app with _layouts/appregnew.aspx, generated client ID and client secret, and copied those values to my add-in before deploy

**STEP 1** - When clicking on app as "installing user"
[image]

**STEP 2** - Approving the app as tenant administrator
[image]

**STEP 3** - Back as "installing user".
[image]

When going back to app-->Information I still get the message from step 1 and its stuck on last version

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are some changes to the approval step.

After your first step, go to the App catalog >  App Requests list as below:

[image]

Now click on the App in the app request lists. Since, you are tenant admin, you should see the below screen. Click on the **Approve** button here.

[image]

3) Now, go to your site and install and trust the app again. It should work now.

Comment: Thanks :D, this worked! This is literally insane (in the artificial membrane)! How can the old flow still be there if you happen to click on the edit-icon->properties and then approve, AND JUST NOT WORK without any information whatsoever, nor any error messages!!! grrr... Anyway, thanks a bunch, it has been driving me koko

Comment: This deserves more than one upvote!